# D-Link DNS "Standard" RAID Type missing disk space

Tags: raid

After first time formatting of 3TB HDD (single disk) using D-Link DNS 320 as "Standard" RAID type (using very hardware soft via HTTP GUI) got 732 GB free space available.
There are no other options for single disk RAID configuration available in "Disk management tool".
According to documentation, as for me, I should have all of 3TB disk space without any RAID enhancements.

What am I missing?  Could it be some kind of hardware issue, how could I verify?

Comment: Check if your disk is either formatted with GPT or if it is a 4K disk with MBR. Regular 512b disk and 3TiB will not work in many cases. It will count up to 2TiB, then wrap around and count the remaining 700-ish MiB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAID will not work with a single disk.  At least two are needed. That does not explain the capcity issue however.  have you checked with D-Link to see if there is a known issue with the drive you have?  Any BIOS/Firmware update for the DNS-320?

There are a number of posts regarding use of 3TB drives with this device and firmware.  Theya re older but you should check your firmware.  [D-Link Support](http://www.dlink.ca/products/?pid=DNS-320) indicates version 2.02 "Fixed 3TB Support".

Comment: http://nas-tweaks.net/364/d-link-releases-updated-firmware-2-02-for-the-dns-320/